# PHP shorthand for isset()?

Tags: php, isset, shorthand

Is there a shorthand way to assign a variable to something if it doesn't exist in PHP?

```
if(!isset($var) {
  $var = "";
}
```

I'd like to do something like

```
$var = $var | "";
```

Comment: Does `$val = isset($var) ? $var : '';` the job for you?

Comment: I found this post very useful: http://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators

Comment: Better original to this duplicate: [Best way to give a variable a default value (simulate Perl ||, ||= )](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5972516/2157640)

Answer (score 330, accepted):

**Update for PHP 7** (thanks [shock_gone_wild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18603250/php-shorthand-for-isset/18603279?noredirect=1#comment56452162_18603279))

PHP 7 introduces the *null coalescing operator* which simplifies the below statements to:

```
$var = $var ?? "default";
```

**Before PHP 7**

No, there is no special operator or special syntax for this. However, you could use the ternary operator:

```
$var = isset($var) ? $var : "default";
```

Or like this:

```
isset($var) ?: $var = 'default';
```

Comment: Here is a link to new features of PHP7 (including null coalescing operator): http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php

Comment: In addition to assignment statements this operator can also be used in function arguments.

Comment: You may want to use something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/9555794/171318

Comment: @MakashovNurbol on my setup PHP 7.1.11 it works with arrays.

Comment: php 7.0 doesn't work with arrays. upgrade if possible

Comment: so-called?... lol it's not "so-called" when it's actually called that. This answer is unnecessarily rude.

Comment: @Sunhat Thanks for showing me this, it was not my intention to be rude. fyi: I'm from Germany and made a translation error. Translated to German naively, `so-called` has a different, not rude meaning. It just means "a thing with name X" where X is a name supposed to be new to the reader.

Comment: @Sunhat I've just checked a German-English language forum, people suggest "an operator which is known as X" instead of "so-called X". Again, thanks for showing me this. I must have made this 1000 times wrong before :)

Comment: My apologies for that interpretation then!! - That's cool and interesting to know too!

Answer (score 77):

**PHP 7.4+**; with the [*null coalescing assignment operator*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration74.new-features.php#migration74.new-features.core.null-coalescing-assignment-operator)

```
$var ??= '';
```

**PHP 7.0+**; with the [*null coalescing operator*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op)

```
$var = $var ?? '';
```

**PHP 5.3+**; with the [*ternary operator* shorthand](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration53.new-features.php#migration53.new-features)

```
isset($var) ?: $var = '';
```

Or for **all/older versions** with *isset*:

```
$var = isset($var) ? $var : '';
```

or

```
!isset($var) && $var = '';
```