# Shorthand isset(), if not, return default value

Tags: php, isset, shorthand

I'm looking for a shorthand version of this code in PHP:

```
$address = isset($node->field_naam_adres['und'][0]['value']) ? $node->field_naam_adres['und'][0]['value'] : '';
```

Basically, I want to check if the variable is set, and if not, then return a default value.

Comment: Isn't that what that code is doing? It's checking for `$node->field_naam_adres['und'][0]['value']` and if it's not set it returns a default value of `''`

Comment: This is the shortest you are going to get unfortunately. It is already the shorthand of the standard if else statment.

Comment: It just annoys me i have to put '$node->field_naam_adres['und'][0]['value']' twice :p

Comment: Cleaned up typos in title and body, added punctuation, removed salutation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18603279/165330 :

before php 7 : no

`$address = isset($node->field_naam_adres['und'][0]['value']) ? $node->field_naam_adres['und'][0]['value'] : '';`

from php 7 : yes

`$address = $node->field_naam_adres['und'][0]['value'] ?? 'default';`

Comment: One could use the "dirty" way and suppress all warnings/notices by using this `@$node->field_naam_adres['und'][0]['value'] ?: '';` in php < 7

Answer (score 0):

If you can get away with relying on truthiness and falsiness instead of the more direct `isset`, you can leave out the middle statement in a ternary like this:

```
$address = $node->field_naam_adres['und'][0]['value'] ?: '';
```

This works such that if the return value of the first statement evaluates as truthy, that value will be returned, otherwise the fallback will be used. You can see what various values will evaluate to as booleans [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting)

It's important to note that if you use this pattern, you cannot wrap your initial statement in `isset`, `empty`, or any similar function. If you do, the return value from that statement simply becomes a boolean value. So while the above code will return either the value of `$node->field_naam_adres['und'][0]['value']` or an empty string, the following code:

```
$address = isset($node->field_naam_adres['und'][0]['value']) ?: '';
```

Will return either `TRUE` or an empty string.

Comment: But `isset()` avoids the notice when you try to read a not-set value. That's why you use isset. So this does something else. The actual answer is: you can't get it shorter.