# Shortest code possible to show html if isset in php

Tags: php, html

I am using php to build my website. but there is many if condition in my php code and if condition isset than i want to show some div in html.

```
<?php if(isset($checkbox1)){ ?>
<div class="btn_simple hidden-xs category align_center col-xs-12 col-md-2 col-md-pull-10  ">
    <div class="side-header">Filter</div>
    <form method="GET">
        <div>
            <strong><?php echo $checkbox1 ?></strong> <input style="width: 50px;" name="<?php echo $checkbox1 ?>" type="checkbox"><
            br>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-offset-1"> <strong> <?php echo $checkbox1?></strong> <input style="width: 50px;margin-right: -6px;" name="<?php echo $checkbox2 ?>" type="checkbox"><br> </div>
        <input style="margin-right:-27px;" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"><br>
        <?php if(isset($_GET['submit']) ){ ?> <a style="margin-right: -27px;width:64px;" class="btn btn_all_images" href="?<?php echo $s_value_1 ?>=&<?php echo $s_value_2 ?>=&submit=submit">All</a>
        <?php } ?>
    </form>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

In this code I have to write:

```
  <?php if(isset($checkbox1)){ ?>
  <?php } ?>
```

Is there any short way to do it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP shorthand for isset()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18603250/php-shorthand-for-isset)

Comment: If you need more shorthand, try any template engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are in way of plain old PHP.

In this case,
theres no way to make it short.

Try to use MVC framework like Laravel.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using PHP7, you can use [Null coalescing operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op)

```
$myVar = $myVar ?? "default value";
// shorthand of $myVar = isset($myVar) ? $myVar : "default value"
```

Comment: Use php short hand <? ?>.

Comment: *[PHP also allows for short open tag <? (which is discouraged since it is only available if enabled using the short_open_tag php.ini configuration file directive, or if PHP was configured with the --enable-short-tags option)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php)*